# Nginx with SSL package

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying to install nginx using the package manager. Usually I'd do this:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

but I need nginx to have SSL support. I could compile nginx from source with SSL support, but I'd like to use a package manager just to make it easier to upgrade or remove if I need to.

Does the `nginx` package compile with SSL support or is there a way to make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The package `nginx-full` installs ssl support as well.

Please refer to this guide to configure your ssl

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule

Comment: beware - nginx-full currently installs nginx 1.1.19 which is a couple of versions old.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate - is the thing, which the websites have unique. Nginx can't provide preinstalled certs, because as i said - 1 cert for 1 site. The SSL certificates are paid, and expire after a while. So, the only way you can get totally FREE SSL certificate - is using [certbot](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04). This program gets Free SSL Certificates from Let's Encrypt authority. They're have no differencies beetween paid ones (except short duration - 2 months). But you can set automatical renew. I'm using this certificates, and I'm pretty wondered that SSL certificate can be free. So the you can follow those [steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) to get SSL on your website.

But you'll need a domain.
**EDIT:** nginx package already supports SSL. You don't need to install other packages.
Just use

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```